# What are the limitations of a device with 256 MB of RAM?

Tags: low-end-devices

Windows Phone 7 Tango adds support for devices with 256 MB of RAM. Will I encounter any major problems if I purchase a device such as the Nokia Lumia 610?

Comment: The Lumia 610 is entry level, so really only for people switching over from a feature phone to a smartphone. My parents were still using the Samsung E250 after 5 years, despite the phones barely functioning anymore, so I convinced them to get the 610 as a starting point. Nice phone, but the aforementioned 256MB RAM is not going to let you do much more than the basics. I've noticed WhatsApp takes quite a while to start up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the main limitations:

- You will not be able to install some applications. A very large list can be found [here](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/14920_What_apps_are_incompatible_wit.php).
- You cannot manage podcast subscriptions or watch video podcasts on your phone.
- Automatic uploading of photos to SkyDrive will not work.
- [Some video codecs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Video_playback_guidance_for_Nokia_Lumia_610) will not work: VC1 Advanced profile (a common WMV format), MPEG-4 Pt 2 Advanced-Simple profile, and MPEG-4 Pt 2 (for 512-MB devices). I think this more has to do with the CPU than RAM.
- [Local Scout](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/web/local-scout.aspx) will not be available.
- Background agents (generic: Resource-intensive tasks and Periodic tasks) are not supported.
- Applications available for fast application switching will be [killed more frequently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202866%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) .

Comment: Please feel free to edit and add to this answer.

Comment: Photosynth [wont work](http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-release-photosynth-windows-phone-marketplace) in Nokia 610 too. Bad.